# Archiving records from PostgreSQL database that surpass timeline

Tags: database, postgresql, database-replication

Let's say we have a database for a bus company.

- We collect data about bus rides, passenger lists, fuel etc.
- We mostly work with data about upcoming rides
- Sometimes we need to look in the history (for accounting), but the time frame is short (3 months at max).
- We don't want to keep all the records on our production/development servers for obvious reasons (storage waste, slow queries etc.).
- We want to have separate database where we would archive whole history.
- What would be the best way to achieve this on PostgreSQL?

We're looking for something like this:

- We want to replicate production database (including structure changes, sequences etc.)
- We want to delete old data from production database, but exclude these statements from the replication to keep archive untouched.

Example:

- When a bus trip is older than 3 months, delete it from production DB, but keep it in the archive DB, where it already is.

What we are currently looking into:

- Some kind of Master/Slave replication (Slony?).
- ENABLE REPLICA RULE for specific tables where we amend DELETE/UPDATE statements with some time rules (WHERE date < NOW() - interval '6 months')

Thanks for your insights.

Comment: I would consider a [Foreign Data Wrapper](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers) with a query run on a schedule (cron job or similar). Keep it simple. Less chance for mistakes or confusion this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an area where logical replication (something like Bucardo or Slony) can really help, since you can replicate only the tables you want and maintain your own triggers around them.  In this case you could have update and delete triggers to archive old versions of the data so you can look over it.

Of course you can also do this with triggers in your production database and then use foreign data wrappers as the comment suggests.  But if you are going that route, you might also consider copying to csv and the loading so you have an air gap and an do transformations if eventually required.